# How to do the same operation on multiple pages without creating a new page Object class

Tags: testing, browser, groovy, geb

In Geb, I have a page www.something.com/ and a page that has an exact layout, except content is different. (For ex. www.something.com/?pg=2) I have a Page class declared.

```
class SearchPage extends Page
{
static url = "www.something.com"
static content =
  {
  //my content declarations
  }
  def mySpecialFunction(){..}
}
```

I can call mySpecialFunction on this searchpage(www.something.com/) by using page.mySpecialFucntion(), but I'm just unsure how to call myspecialFunction() on www.something.com/?pg=2, then www.something.com/?pg=3, and so on. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have it figured out! It was quite simple(as is everything in groovy/geb)

When you navigate to a page, you can add arguements to it via

```
to SearchPage, "?pg=2"
```

I then abstracted the number to repeat the action across multiple pages

```
for(int i =0; endCondition(); i++){
  mySpecialFunction()
  to SearchPage, "?pg=${i}"
}
```